# Next best thing to solution of linear program

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Assume I have a linear program in the form
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{a} \leq A\mathbf{x} \leq \mathbf{c}
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $A$ an $m \times n$ matrix. This has a solutions if there are vectors $\mathbf{b}$ in the column space of $A$ that fulfil $\mathbf{a} \leq \mathbf{b} \leq \mathbf{c}$. If there is no solution, what's the easiest linear (or even quadratic) program to solve in order to find the vectors that are closest to a solution in terms of $2$-norm or $1$-norm for example?

Comment: $a=a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_m\le b=b_1+b_2+\cdots +b_m\le c=c_1+c_2+\cdots c_m$ try maybe using the norm ineqaulity? $|.|_\infty <|.|_2<|.|_1<\sqrt m |.|_\infty$

Comment: It is sort of up to you, because there are many ways you can define what you mean by the rather vague "being as close as possible to the solution of an infeasible problem". For example you could minimize $t$ such that $a-t\leq Ax\leq c+t$. Or you could find $x$ that minimizes $max(Ax-c,b-Ax,0)$. Etc. Some might be more suited to your application than others.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek the thing is that I don't have a strict requirement for my application, it would be great if the program is linear and always solvable

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek for example if i took your first suggestion and minimized the 2-norm of $t$ it would probably become a quadratic problem, and it would always admit a solution, I think. Is this intuition correct?

Comment: Yes, an elasticity model, as I think it is sometimes called, always has a solution because ultimately there is a large enough value of a slack variable that will satisfy it. I was thinking $t$ is a single scalar, but of course it can also be a vector that you minimize the 2-norm of (quadratic problem) or 1- or inf-norm (linear problem). Like I said you have many options.